# Tortoise SVN GUI closing update window

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Until recently the Tortoise SVN Gui was pausing after I updated to show me which files it was updating, and waited to close until I clicked **Okay**. Then I started sending TortoiseProc.exe commands using the command line also (and created some .bat files containing the commands, to automate committing some files).

Now the GUI version seems stuck on closing the window automatically after updates, without waiting for my confirmation. This is a problem since I need to see what it updated. I can view the log, but before I could just read the window before I closed it.

My commands in the .bat files are similar to this:

```
TortoiseProc.exe  /command:update /path:"C:\<myfilepath>.js" /closeonend:0
```

The commands are supposed to do the following:

```
/closeonend:0 don't close the dialog automatically
/closeonend:1 auto close if no errors
/closeonend:2 auto close if no errors and conflicts
/closeonend:3 auto close if no errors, conflicts and merges
```

My GUI version is now acting as if :1 is set. I've read some things online that say that you can set this in the Tortoise SVN Gui "Settings" also, but I don't see a setting. It's possible that my company has restricted or not included it.

It seems as if the command line has altered the way the GUI is behaving, but the above 0 command should reset it in that case, you would think anyway.

Note that I can't install other tools since I can't install anything, plus I have to use the Tortoise SVN GUI version anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting in the GUI is located under the "Dialogs 1" settings page:

[image: Settings UI showing auto close option]

As far as I know, the batch file calls should not affect this setting, so I can't speak to what would have caused that.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. Had just missed it.